# Displayport KVM switch not passing signal if Adaptive HDMI to Displayport Cable/Adapter and Displayport to DVI cable used

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, displayport, kvm-switch

I bought a Displayport KVM switch to switch between two PCs using the same two monitors and I cannot get one of the monitors to work if I use an Adaptive HDMI to Displayport Cable/Adapter and Displayport to DVI cable either side of the KVM. Its easiest to show in a diagram as below. The first diagram shows the problem (Red route).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9spxhd7vepmtg5/KVM%20DisplayPort%20Issue.JPG?dl=1

[image: Diagram]

My 2 monitors only have DVI and VGA inputs. What I cant understand is that if I borrow a 3rd monitor with a DP input and connect this (3rd Diagram), the HDMI>DP cable/adapter works as there is a DP>DP cable between KVM and Monitor, but it wont work if there is a DP>DVI cable between KVM and Monitor.

I went with a Displayport KVM as opposed to a DVI one as my PC2 GPU only has DP outputs and my PC1 GPU has 1 DP output and I figured I could get a HDMI>DP adapter for its HDMI output. And I had two DP>DVI cables anyway.

I've tried two different HDMI>DP adapters/cables. Neither worked and they are pricey so don't want to have to purchase a third. If I could confirm an adaptive DPI>DP adapter would work I would purchase one of these instead.

Comment: Perhaps the KVM itself is an active converter and can only convert for one side at a time? (Because of chip design or processing power or so?) Does it spec even mention that it can do TMDS (HDMI/DVI) passthrough?

Comment: Also AFAIK passive HDMI/DVI (source) to DP (sink) connection is not standardized, so the fact its DP ports can accept HDMI/DVI source is probably some "proprietary" trick/hack.

Comment: This is the KVM:
https://depzol.com/products/depzol-2-port-kvm-switch-dual-monitor-displayport-4096x2160-60hz-dual-view-keyboard-video-mouse-selector-for-dp-computers-laptops-2-in-2-out-with-audio-and-usb-2-0-hubs-support-dp-1-2-622dp

Comment: Manual is here: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0277/9951/9316/files/Dual_Monitor_KVM_User_Manual_REV190809.pdf?81

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be, the KVM is a purely passive device that supports and supports only the DP standard (including dual-mode, a.k.a. DP++), therefore it will work with:

1. connection involve DP and DP only (obviously)
2. a DP++ source (PC) and a TMDS sink (Monitor), i.e. [PC]DP->DP[KVM]DP->HDMI/DVI[Monitor]

(NOTE: actually the second case probably will not require any explicit support in the KVM as the source itself is responsible for the detection; as long as the KVM, or you,  doesn't do anything silly in the middle that blocks/hinders such detection, it will work)

The problem probably lies in the HDMI-to-DP adapter/cable. Unlike DP(++-to-HDMI), there's no such thing as "passive" HDMI-to-DP conversion. I cannot say for sure which kind of adapter/cable you got, but what I suspect now is, the one has chip to do TMDS to DP *signal conversion*.

That's the reason why the "diagram 3" case work, because with an "active" cable, from the KVM/sink's point of view, it is the same case as the first one I listed above.

Now let's back to the case where it doesn't work. For a TMDS sink (the DVI monitor in this case) to work, the source side must be a DP++ port, which can detect it for being such a sink and send TMDS signal instead of DP signal.

So for your desired connection to work, you'll need a cable so adaptive that it works like DP++ port, that is, it needs to support TMDS sink and passthrough the TMDS signal it receives when it detects such sink being connected to it.

The thing is I doubt that such adapter chip/solution ever existed on the market, as it's not exactly something sensical to support / invest in except in corner case like yours. (Although it does not really violate any standard and should be theoretically feasible, as far as I'm concerned; just that I don't think any vendor would bother to produce such product.)

Now someone may say, what about a "passive" HDMI-to-DP cable? Sorry, such thing does not exist either (what exists is DP(++)-to-HDMI), as there's no "HDMI++" that allows DP signal to be transmitted over HDMI, and just as I'm telling, it won't help in your not-working case either even if it exists in some parallel world. It would at best save you the active adapter/cable/signal conversion in the diagram 3 case.

<strike>So my conclusion is, you'll need either the KVM or the monitor or the graphic card/motherboard replaced.</strike>

TL;DR, the DP-to-DVI adapter/cable(s) you have are most likely passive one(s). Get an active one (for the monitor that is connected to the HDMI source / active HDMI-to-DP adapter), it will likely get things work. [(Example that has "active" clearly stated on the packaging)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HJZQGVQ) [(Another one)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004SUO1GM)

Comment: DP > DVI Cable is below. It looks to be passive alright:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07FZLGN6S/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Thanks for help. I will buy an active DP>DVI adapter and see if it works and post back

Comment: So I bought an active DP>DVI adapter and its still not working. The adapter is DP male to DVI female. And I then have a standard DVI male to male cable connection between the adapter and monitor. Do I need a specific DVI cable here?

Comment: I don't think so. It's just that because of the kvm in between / the source not being DP from the start, I wonder if you need an adapter that takes dedicated external power from a USB port or whatever.

Comment: Either way it's still just all theory from me, so don't have too much expectation that it could actually work with such double conversion chain.

Comment: KVM reads EDID and knows 2 DVI monitors are attached. The KVM firmware is programmed to know that some graphics cards support dual mode (DP++) and send HDMI signal through the DP++ port when HDMI monitors are detected. Hence, DP++ -> KVM -> DVI works because KVM passes through incoming HDMI signal to DVI monitor. Exotic case involving a DP->DVI converter is apparently not considered by Depzol KVM. So it probably just blocks the incoming DP signal when a DVI/HDMI monitor is attached as it has no means of knowing that there is a a DP->DVI active converter between it and the DVI monitor.